# Vonk FHIR Facade - Vonk Server could not load file or assembly System.Runtime

Tags: c#, .net-core, hl7-fhir, dstu2-fhir

As I implement Vonk FHIR Facade using the [link](http://docs.simplifier.net/vonk/facade/facade.html), I've performed all steps successfully uptil [this point](http://docs.simplifier.net/vonk/facade/debugging.html) and placed the resulting dlls in *plugins* directory.

Now when I start the Vonk server, it fails with following error:

> Startup Failed: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublishToken=xxxxxxxxxx' The system cannot find the file specified.

I've build my Vonk Facade project in .NET Core 2.1.

Any solution or workaround would be highly appreciated.

Comment: For a follow-up, see discussion here: https://github.com/FirelyTeam/Vonk.Facade.Starter/issues/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @Alexander Zuatke and Firely team, we found that Vonk server v2.0.0.0 still targets netcoreapp 2.0 internally.

So we have to target our development project i.e. Vonk Facade to .NET Core 2.0